# Design Pattern for Event Based Auction and selling system

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to build a prototype for  auction app.

Seller will always create a event which will be of two types

- 1) auction of item
- 2) fixed price event(The number of types may increase in future)

Since both auction type and fixed price event will have start date and end date, but other items are totally different. so I am confused which design pattern i should follow to instantiate proper event type based on use selection of event type from the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "other items are totally different" ?

The way I see it each auction have:

```
Start DateTime
End DateTime
Title
Price
Shipping or else fees
Description
Product/w.e images[]
```

etc..

Why can't all auction be contained in a same type of structure?

Saying this.. Composite pattern comes into mind, but just if im right on the above.

[Composite Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html)

Also a fixed price type could ALSO be an "auction" of FixedPrice type.

So add an Enum to the above structure.

```
enum AuctionType
{
FixedPrice,
Charity,
Free,
Promotion,
Whatever
}
```

Comment: fixed price is totally not a auction it will only have start date and end date but there will be no bidding in fixed price user will directly purchase the item instead of bidding.

Answer (score 0):

Your Object Model can be

Auction  class

Event - base class.

AuctionEvent - Inherit from Event .

FixedPriceAuctionEvent

Auction is a property of AuctionEvent .

This way you have multiple type of AuctionEvent class. They may have different properties, still have Auction property.

When you channel inputs to the system via Events you will have a record of inputs to the system. When you have events and subevents you will get a picture of what type of input it is . This helps in deriving the process logic and and can have more clear audit history.